# Add to Database objects of different types

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I Have got database with tables (`Resistor`, `Transistor`, `Capacitor` ... etc.). I All Dbsets are inherit base class `DomainObject`.

I have generic DataService<T> to access to db.

```
 public class GenericDataService<T> : IDataService<T> where T : DomainObject
 {
   private readonly OperationMapsDbContextFactory _dbContextFactory;
   public GenericDataService(OperationMapsDbContextFactory dbContextFactory)
   {
     _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
   }
   public async Task<T> Create(T entity)
   {
     using (OperationMapsDbContext context = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
     {
       EntityEntry<T> createdResult = await context.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
       await context.SaveChangesAsync();
       return createdResult.Entity;
    }
}
```

I have list `List<DomainObject> allItems`.

```
public class Program
{
    public static List<DomainObject> allItems;
    public static DbContextFactory dbContextFactory = new DbContextFactory();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       allItems = new List<DomainObject>
       {
         new Resistor(),
         new Capacitor(),
         new Transitor(),
       }
    }
}


public static void AddItemsToDataBase()
{
  foreach(var item in allItems)
  {
    IDataService<> dataService = new GenericDataService<>(dbContextFactory) // How to init generic class with correct type depeinding on item
    dataService.Create(_domainObject); // How to cast domainObject to its real type depending on item?
  }
}
```

Now i did it with switch case. every DbSet class has enum value of its type.

```
enum ItemType{
Resistor,
Transisor, 
Capacitor
```

And method for adding elements looks

```
public static void AddItemsToDataBase()
{
  foreach(var item in allItems)
  {
    switch(item.ItemType)
    {
      case(Resistor):
        IDataService<Resistor> dataService = new GenericDataService<Resistor>(dbContextFactory) 
        dataService.Create((Resistor)_domainObject); 
      break;
      case(Transistor):
        IDataService<Transistor> dataService = new GenericDataService<Transistor>(dbContextFactory) 
        dataService.Create((Transistor)_domainObject); 
      break;
      case(Capacitor)
        IDataService<Capacitor> dataService = new GenericDataService<Capacitor>(dbContextFactory) 
        dataService.Create((Capacitor)_domainObject); 
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

So how to implement this function in right way without switch/case?

Comment: Btw, you should not use `AddAsync`/`RemoveAsync` on DbSets, those methods do not work asynchronously and were added by Microsoft for some of their test cases. Use regular `Add`/`Remove` so you won't create unnecessary `Task` objects.

Comment: My question is how to add items more clearly with out switch/case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add entities in `DbContext` it is not necessary to reference specific `DbSet`. It would be enough to call `context.Add(entity);`.

In case your service just creates the `DbContext` instance and then adds your entity - it's pretty much pointless, since you're making your code more complex for a too-low price. The most efficient way would be something like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static List<DomainObject> allItems;
    public static DbContextFactory dbContextFactory = new DbContextFactory();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        allItems = new List<DomainObject>
        {
            new Resistor(),
            new Capacitor(),
            new Transitor(),
        }
    }
}


public static async void AddItemsToDataBase()
{
    using var context = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();

    context.AddRange(allItems);

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

You might ask - what if I need to get the result back like I had in my `Create` method? - Well, your entities in that list would be updated anyway so you can reference them. Or if you need to add records one by one - you can go with `context.Add` method, which will also return you the `EntityEntry` result, containing information about the new record.

**UPDATE**

There might be a lot of business cases when you need to reference multiple tables at a time. I'd suggest you to create an aggregator table. So you'd have another entity, something like `ElectricComponent`, which will have optional foreign keys for `Resistor`, `Transistor`, and `Capacitor`. Each of them, in return, would have a foreign key `ElectricComponentId`. After such modification, you'd be able to query this aggregation table and retrieve results for all sub-tables.

So when you create your resistors, transistors, and capacitors - you automatically create a new `ElectrictComponent` entry. You can modify the constructors of your entities to make it implicit.

```
public class Resistor
{
    public Resistor()
    {
        if (ElectricComponentId == default)
            ElectricComponent = new();
    }

    public int/Guid ElectricComponentId { get; set; }

    public ElectricComponent ElectricComponent { get; set; }
    //
    // Your logic here.
    //
}
```

After such changes you can reference this table to check any other:

```
using var context = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
var allComponents = context.Set<ElectricComponent>();

var resistorsExists = await allComponents.AnyAsync(component => component.ResistorId != null);
```

Comment: Hello, now I am faced with another problem. I need to check if the database contains elements of different types in the list (resistor, transistor, capacitor). There is a good solution without switch/case?

Comment: @IliyaBelan edited my answer, check it.

Comment: Thank you very match. So Class 'ElectricComponent' should contains `ResistorId`, `TransistorId` `CapacitorId` etc... ?

Comment: @IliyaBelan, yeah, just nullable foreign keys for each of your entities of such 'group'

Answer (score 0):

You should have a non-generic version of the IDataService interface that your generic IDataService extends

```
public static void AddItemsToDataBase()
{
    foreach (var item in allItems)
    {
        Type itemType = item.GetType();
        Type dataServiceType = typeof(GenericDataService<>).MakeGenericType(itemType);
        IDataService dataService = (IDataService)Activator.CreateInstance(dataServiceType, dbContextFactory);

        // Now you can call the Create method on dataService without needing to cast item
        dataService.Create(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand, that this is just a basic example, but in case there would be 10000 items to add - this code will create 10000 instances of dbcontext and services. This solution needs to have some caching feature.